# Implicit declaration of function 'fork' error (with unistd.h included, on Windows)

Tags: c, posix, unistd.h

Trying to write a simple program involving processes for school, and I keep getting the above error, as well as the same implicit declaration error for `pipe` commands.

I'm:

- on Windows
- supposed to run POSIX related commands
- using VScode (if applicable)
- using MinGW for my headers and compiling

**Here are my headers:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

**here are just some of the commands being used:**

```
int PtoC[2], CtoP[2];
    pipe(PtoC);
    pipe(CtoP);
    
    int child_pid = fork();

    if(child_pid < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }
```

**The output when I try to compile with gcc:**

```
In function 'main':
digits_sol.c:37:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pipe' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     pipe(PtoC);
     ^~~~
digits_sol.c:40:21: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fork' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     int child_pid = fork();
```

I've tried messing around with my `.json` settings file to include the `unistd.h` file

```
"name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\MinGW\\include**"
            ],
```

for some reason, my MinGW folder has a `unistd.h` in the `MinGW\include` directory, and also in the `MinGW\include\sys` directory

I'm not sure why my instructor wouldn't tell me how to run POSIX functions on windows, and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Windows isn't POSIX and doesn't support a lot of POSIX functions like `fork()` (It does has a version of `pipe()` called [`_pipe()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/pipe?view=msvc-170) that takes additional arguments). You're better off working in a WSL2 installation or a VM running Linux or a BSD instead of trying to compile on Windows.

Comment: @Shawn this helped, thanks! got a Ubuntu WSL running on VScode (dk if thats best practice) and its working.